# How to implement cascading deletes in one -> many *from the many side*

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a use case where multiple rows in table A are aggregated down to a single row in table B.  We represent the origin of rows in table B with a foreign key column in table A, saying "as a row, I contributed to X row in table B".

We want to find the best solution so that once every row from table A which contributed to table B has been deleted, deleted the row in table B as an orphan.

I'm not sure if there's some way to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` to handle this.  But I'm guessing not and that maybe triggers are the best option.

I can't just purge *all* orphans on a schedule because the changes need to be persisted very soon after occurring.

Using the given schema, what our best option?  Alternatively, is there some other schema that better sets us up for the scenario I gave?

Comment: I'd bet money your trigger thought is correct. There's no way a CASCADE can check the relevant condition: Are there other rows that refer to this one? This is the kind of thing triggers are for.

Comment: I would include a counter in table B. Every time a row in A contributes to the row in table B the counter is incremented. When a row in A is deleted, the counter is decremented; if it reaches zero, then delete the row in table B.